# How to use always the same type of edge in a directed weighted graph?

Tags: c++, graph, path, dijkstra

I'm doing a project for college and we are simulating a public transport (Only bus) system using directed weighted graphs in c++. Each node represents a stop and each edge represents the line of the bus and the line is a parameter of the edge besides the weight. So between stops we can have multiple buses doing that bit of the trip. I'm using the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path in distance but I would like to add another option which is to choose the path with the least line changes (i.e. even if the path is longer, choose the one that uses always the same bus).

I've thought about implementing it with binary weight but I'm not sure if it would work.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each node where there are more than one line, split the node into several connected by edges with weight the cost of changing lines.  The run Dijkstra.

Comment: I think I understood your solution but I guess that's what I have. Between each node there's an edge for each line that there is. But the weight that needs to be added is dependent on which line it used before, and that may vary because there's multiple combinations to reach the same stop.

Comment: "the weight that needs to be added is dependent on which line it used before"  You split the node into separate nodes for each line.  The cost of witching between line A and line B is the cost of the edge between node A and node B.